# c# where in with list and linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-in

I have two lists, one have a list of `object A` an other a list of `objects B`, like this:

```
ObjectA
{
    Int64 idObjectA;
    String name;
    ....
}

ObjectB
{
    Int64 idObjectB;
    Int64 idObjectA;
    String name;
    ....
}
```

I have two list, one with `Object A` and other with `Object B`. I want to create a new `list C` that have only `objects B`, which `IDObjectA` is any `ID` of the `list A`.

In SQL it would be somthing line that:

```
select * from B where IDObjectA IN(1,2,3,4...);
```

In my case, the list of values for the `IN clause` is the list of `ObjectA`, which have the property `idObjectA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same with Join and without Contains:

```
var listC = listB.Join(listA, b => b.ObjectAId, a => a.Id, (b, a) => b).ToList();
```

Comment: this solution has a linear o quadratic complexity? The only difference is the syntaxis? Thanks.

Comment: @Daimroc It is exactly same solution than mine (in _O(n)_). Raubi uses the LINQ extension methods syntax, I use the query-syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) linq method to achieve this by joining `listB` and `listA` by their `idObjectA`, then select `itemB`.

```
var result = (from itemB in listB
              join itemA in listA on itemB.idObjectA equals itemA.idObjectA
              select itemB).ToList();
```

This method has a linear complexity (`O(n)`). Using `Where(... => ....Contains())` or double `foreach` has a quadratic complexity (`O(n^2)`).

Comment: Excellent answer, however in 99% of the cases, `ToList` is superfluous. (I'm assuming that the term `List` in the question was used to refer to any sequence `IEnumerable<T>` as opposed to a `List<T>`.)

Comment: The the solution from Gideon has a complexity in _O(n^2)_, less efficient than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Not linq, but does what you want it to:

```
List<ObjectB> C = new List<ObjectB>();
foreach (n in B)
{
    foreach (c in A)
    {
        if (n.idObjectA == c.idObjectA)
        {
            C.Add(n)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted higher performance, use a for, and higher than that use Cédric Bignon's solution.

Comment: The complexity of this operation is quadratic. Linq provides powerful method to make it linear (or close to linear).

Comment: @CédricBignon No, I wrote that YOURS has higher performance than mine. By far. I have no idea where you got that from.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different way of doing it as opposed to a join.

```
List<ObjectA> listA = ..
List<ObjectB> listB = ..
int[] listAIds = listA.Select(a => a.idObjectA).ToList();
               //^^ this projects the list of objects into a list of ints

//It reads like this...

//get items in listB WHERE..
listB.Where(b => listAIds.Contains(b.idObjectA)).ToList();
//b.idObjectA is in listA, OR where listA contains b.idObjectA
```

Comment: If not optimized by the compiler this is a very heavy operation because for each item in listB the runtime constructs a new list with all ids of listA and additionally performs a linear search.

Comment: You can simplify your expression with: _listA.Any(a => a.idObjectA = b.idObjectA)_ (not to instanciate a list for each element in b). But this operations is still _O(n^2)_.

Comment: @Jasd Good catch!! I fixed it. I just wanted to show a different approach so the OP can see his options and understand linq. (I know a lot of people who don't know how to leverage select projections)

Comment: Yes, sometimes is difficult to undertand linq. It's good to have examples and to compare the complexity is a very good. Thanks.